# How to use internationalization api for js?

Tags: javascript

I am using the number format option: curCode =‘JPY’

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency:curCode}).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"
```

How can I return:

```
JPY 123,457
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const number = 123457;
const curCode = "JPY";
const formattingOptions = {style: 'currency', currency: curCode, currencyDisplay: 'code'};
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', formattingOptions);
const regex = new RegExp(`${curCode}\\s*`, "g");

let result = numberFormat.format(number).replace(regex,`${curCode} `);

console.log(result);
```

The [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat#Parameters) options include a `currencyDisplay` property for this purpose.

> **`currencyDisplay`**
>
> How to display the currency in currency formatting. Possible values are `"symbol"` to use a localized currency symbol such as `€`, `"code"` to use the ISO currency code, `"name"` to use a localized currency name such as `"dollar"`; the default is `"symbol"`.

**EDIT:**

> And if I want to add a space before the number?

You could use `.replace(/JPY\s*/g,"JPY ");` to enforce one space between `JPY` and the number.

`\s*` will optionally match all spaces trailing `JPY`, to be sure we aren't adding excess spaces for those whose output already includes a space by default.

**EDIT 2:**

> And what would the regex look if I have an currencycode instead of JPY hardcoded?

You could replace all instances of `JPY` with your variable instead. Given that you'd need the regex to include your variable, you'd have to use the regex constructor (`new RegExp()`) instead.

Comment: And if I want to add a space before the number?

Comment: My output is exactly as you describe: `JPY 123,457` - does your output differ? I hadn't considered that might be part of the localization, though I imagine a simple `.replace()` could resolve that.

Comment: Nope there is no space

Comment: @bierhier Ah okay. My updated answer has added a regex replace that should solve that.

Comment: And what would the regex look if I have an currencycode instead of JPY hardcoded?

Comment: @bierhier Updated.